# How to automate notification of a new user

Tags: command-line, email, minecraft

I would like to have my Minecraft Server (v. 1.14) which runs on Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 send me an email when someone joins my server, including that user's username and uuid. Which kinds of apps are required to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need

1) an email server running on your Ubuntu machine which can send an email to your desired address. There are many email server packages available for Ubuntu.
2) You will also need a package which monitors the new enrollment process in the Minecraft Server which will collect that username and UUID, and  https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support-andmay be a good place to look for that.
3) Lastly, you will need a package which outputs that new user data to generate an email to send, unless #2 also does that.

Once you find #2, the package in Minecraft which will do that, the rest will be easy.  The #2 package may have limitations which will dictate the features required by #1 and #3, so look for that first.